# Basis one-form and basis vector confusion

Tags: differential-geometry

Still trying to teach myself some basic differential geometry in relation to general relativity. I've read that, in relation to basis vectors $e_{\nu}=\partial_{\nu}$ and basis one-forms $\omega^{\mu}=dx^{\mu}$,
  then $$e_{\nu}\omega^{\mu}=\partial_{\nu}dx^{\mu}=\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}}=\delta_{\nu}^{\mu}.$$
 Fair enough, but why does the partial derivative operator $\partial_{\nu}$
  (which I thought meant $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}$
 , where the slot is for an arbitrary function) when applied to $dx^{\mu}$
  give $\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}}$
  and not $\frac{\partial\left(dx^{\mu}\right)}{\partial x^{\nu}}$? Or does $\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}}=\frac{\partial\left(dx^{\mu}\right)}{\partial x^{\nu}}$? But if that's the case what does $\partial_{\nu}x^{\mu}$ give? It can't also be correct that

$$\partial_{\nu}x^{\mu}=\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}}=\delta_{\nu}^{\mu},$$
 but I can't see why not. I'm confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I like Amitai Yuval's answer, but let me try to say something a little more basic.  It's necessarily a bit vague, but maybe it will give you the idea of what's going on.

The coordinates $x^1, \dots, x^n$ define functions on your manifold.  In a physics context, $x^1$, $x^2$ and $x^3$ may represent position with respect to a particular set of axes whilst $x^4$ labels time.  Tangent vectors are little arrows at points in your space, and we have a nice basis at each point given by the arrows pointing along each of the coordinate directions.  In our example these would correspond to arrows in the directions of the $x^1$-, $x^2$- and $x^3$-axes, and a fourth arrow which points forwards in time but has no spatial component.  We write these vectors as $\partial/\partial x^a$ or $\partial_a$, but this is **just notation** for now.

A one-form is 'a thing you plug vectors into': you feed it a vector and it spits out a number which depends linearly on the input.  For each $a$ we can define a one-form $\mathrm{d}x^a$ to be the one-form which gives $1$ when you input $\partial_a$ and $0$ when you input $\partial_b$ for $b \neq a$.  Again this is **just notation**.  In other words, the statement $\mathrm{d}x^a(\partial_b)=\delta^a_b$ is basically a tautology.  Back to our example, if you plug a vector $v$ into $\mathrm{d}x^4$ then what you get out is the time component of $v$.

Now, given a vector $v$ at a point $p$ and a function $f$ defined near $p$ you can take the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $v$, which you could write as $v(f)$ (although personally I don't like this notation).  If you take $v$ to be $\partial_a$ then this directional derivative really just is the partial derivative $\partial f/\partial x^a$.  This is why the notation $\partial_a$ or $\partial/\partial x^a$ is sensible.  So in our example $f$ could be something like density and then $\partial_4(f)$ represents the time-derivative of the density.

Thinking of the vector $v$ in the expression $v(f)$ as variable, we get a thing which takes vectors and spits out numbers (given the vector $v$ it outputs $v(f)$).  In other words it defines a one-form: the differential (or derivative) of $f$, which we write as $\mathrm{d}f$.  Happily, the one-form we defined to be $\mathrm{d}x^a$ purely as a piece of notation really just is the differential of the function $x^a$.

So in terms of directional derivatives it is true that $\partial_a(x^b)=\delta^b_a$.  Whilst in terms of feeding vectors into one-forms it is true that $\mathrm{d}x^a(\partial_b)=\delta^a_b$.  By the above comment about differentials, relating directional derivatives to one-forms, these statements are really saying the same thing.

The expression you write as $\partial_\nu \mathrm{d}x^\mu$ is a bit ambiguous.  It definitely doesn't mean 'differentiate $\mathrm{d}x^\mu$'.  The sensible interpretation (which makes it equal to $\delta^\mu_\nu$) is that you're feeding the one-form into the vector using double-duality.  But this is probably a little too abstract at present.

Comment: Thanks. In your para 2, could an example of these $x^{1}$ etc coordinates on the manifold be Cartesian coordinates $x,y,z$ (assuming we're in Euclidean space). If these coordinates were defined in terms of spherical coordinates $r,\theta,\phi$, we could say $z=r\cos\phi$ and thus $\frac{dz}{dr}=\cos\phi$ and $dz=\cos\phi dr$. Is $dz$ a one-form? Also, in para 4 you say vector $v=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{a}}$. In para 3 you say if we plug $v$ into $dx^{4}$ we get the time component of $v$. But surely $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{a}}dx^{4}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{4}}dx^{4}=1$?

Comment: Yes, if you're in 3d Euclidean space then you could take $x^1$, $x^2$ and $x^3$ to be the Cartesian coordinates.  You're right that $\mathrm{d}z$ is a one-form, but when you pass to spherical coordinates you should get $\mathrm{d}z=\cos \phi \mathrm{d}r-r \sin \phi \mathrm{d}\phi$.

Comment: As I mentioned at the end of my answer, it's a bit ambiguous to write a vector followed by a one-form.  The correct statement is $\mathrm{d}x^4(\partial_a)=\delta^4_a$.  Why do you think you should replace the index $a$ by $4$ in the last line of your comment?

Comment: $\mathrm{d}z/\mathrm{d}r$ is not really a thing, since $z$ is a function of three variables: $r$, $\theta$ and $\phi$ (although it's actually independent of $\theta$).

Comment: Sorry, I meant to use the total differential of $z$ $(\mathrm{d}z=\cos\phi\mathrm{d}r-r\sin\phi\mathrm{d}\phi)$. But at least now that I'm using a simple example, the language of coordinate functions is becoming a little easier to visualise. I used $a=4$ in $\mathrm{d}x^{4}(\partial_{a})=\delta_{a}^{4}$ because any other value would give zero. Does that mean time component of $v$ in this case equals 1?

Comment: I was taken aback to read in your answer that $\partial_{\nu}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}$ “definitely doesn't mean differentiate $\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}$.” That was the one thing I thought I understood in the whole problem, ie differentiating $dx^{1}$ wrt $dx^{1}$ gives 1, wrt to $dx^{a}$ where $a\neq1$ gives zero (because the coordinates are independent of each other). So are are saying $e_{\nu}\omega^{\mu}=\partial_{\nu}dx^{\mu}=\delta_{\nu}^{\mu}$
  only because it is defined to do so and that I'm going to have to forget about my explanation in terms of coordinate independence?

Comment: So are you saying, using my example of $z=r\cos\phi$, that $v\left(f\right)=dz$ where $v=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{a}}$ and $f=z$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30379/discussion-between-jez-and-peter4075).

Answer (score 7):

It is only a matter of notation. There are a few different ways to look at things, the following is one of those ways.

Take a coordinate chart $\varphi:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\varphi$ consists of $n$ real valued functions which we write as $x^1,\ldots,x^n$. The derivative of the $i$th function is $dx^i$, and this is how we get the local frame of the cotangent bundle $dx^1,\ldots,dx^n$.

On the other hand, the chart $\varphi$ also induces a local frame of the tangent bundle, which we write as $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1},\ldots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}.$

Now, there are two standard notations for *the derivative of $f$ in the direction $X$* - one of them is $X(f)$ and the other is $df(X)$. Using the former, we can write$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(x^j)=\delta_i^j,$$whereas the latter yields$$dx^j\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)=\delta_i^j.$$Both equations mean the same.

Comment: I'm afraid that's above my head. Any chance of a more high school level type answer? I'm OK with contravariant vector components as tangent vectors, and one-form components as gradients and that these things live at a point on a manifold (4d for spacetime). I understand that $$e_{\nu}\omega^{\mu}=\delta_{\nu}^{\mu}.$$ But "charts", "bundles" and "$n$ real valued functions" lose me.

Comment: Thanks to Amitai Yuval, but the second paragraph loses me. What are these $n$ real valued functions? Are they coordinate transformations from one chart to another? The reason for my question was trying to understand how the product of a one-form and a contravariant vector gives a scalar. Hence my trying to see how the product of the basis vectors $e_{\nu}\omega^{\mu}$ gives $\delta_{\nu}^{\mu}$. As is painfully obvious, my knowledge of manifolds is via a very basic introduction to the physics of spacetime.

Comment: @Peter4075 I see what you mean. Unfortunately, I don't know how I can help at the moment. It seems to me that you should pick an introductory book on manifolds and find in it the basic terminology. It may take a few days, but if you really want to understand geometry, it is definitely worth the effort.

Answer (score 4):

I found this question because I was having the same problem. I had to figure it out and I believe i did. Way too late for the original questioner, but I respond now for people with the same question. I think this is the solution:

If you were reading somebody's book who uses the same notation as Carroll's book on GR, you probably saw three different d's. Carroll uses $d$ for differentials, $\partial{}$ for partial derivatives and the letter d for a one-form. Note the italics $d$ versus regular d. Schutz uses the ~ with the d and writes $\tilde{\text{d}}$ for a one form, and I like that better.

Now, what I think you saw was  d$x_i (\frac{\partial{}}{dx^i}) =\delta^j_i\;$ and what it meant was $\;\tilde{\text{d}}x_i (\frac{\partial{}}{dx^i}) =\delta^j_i$ and not $\;dx_i (\frac{\partial{}}{dx^i}) =\delta^j_i$. That is, what was being said is that a one-form basis takes the vector basis and produces $\delta$.